# Suspend and Resume a Camel Route

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

Hi i am having a JMS consumer route in camel, my requirement is to stop/suspend that route at certain incident(based on the some field value) and then resume that route using a scheduler. 
For this i have created two routes, one is my original jms consumer route and one is scheduler route, that resume the jms consumer routes, although i am able to suspend the route but second route is not resuming the suspended route and its showing the state as started.

below are my two routes

### original consumer route

```
from("activeMQ:demo.audit.event1?testConnectionOnStartup=true&acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE")
    .routeId("javadslconsumer")
    .log("before stopping==="+new Date().toString())
    .process(new Processor() {
          @Override
          public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
              try {
                  Route route = exchange.getContext().getRoute("javadslconsumer");
                  System.out.println("route.supportsSuspension()"+route.supportsSuspension());
                  exchange.getContext().suspendRoute("javadslconsumer",1l,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                  // create another helper route, using which we can start or resume this route based 
                  // on the current life cycle phase of this route.    
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  // ignore
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        })
    .log("after stopping logs==="+new Date().toString())
    .unmarshal(dataFormat)
    .beanRef("auditProcessor", "getErrorAuditDTO")
    .beanRef("auditProcessor", "processCreateAudit");
```

### scheduler route

```
from("timer:dlqscheduler?period=6000&fixedRate=true")
.process(new Processor(){
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("timer process started");
        try {
            exchange.getContext().resumeRoute("javadslconsumer");
            //exchange.getContext().startRoute("javadslconsumer");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("-----d-d-d-d-"+e.getMessage());
        }
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus  = getContext().getRouteStatus("javadslconsumer");
        System.out.println("serviceStatus.isStopped()"+serviceStatus.isStopped()); // showing false instead of true
        System.out.println("serviceStatus.isSuspended()"+serviceStatus.isSuspended()); // showing false instead of true
        System.out.println("serviceStatus"+serviceStatus);// showing started
    }       
})
.log("after resuming the route javadslconsumer");
```

Please help me how i can implement the above scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give it more time than 1 second. That is a fallback timeout, so if the suspension could not happen within 1 sec it let the route run instead. eg read the javadoc documentation of the API you use, and you can see that information.

Also btw there is a controlbus component so you can just send a message to an endpoint to suspend/resume a route.

- http://camel.apache.org/controlbus

Comment: I tried by increasing the fallback time limit, but no change in the behavior, the status of first route is still showing as started in second route. and i can not use control bus component as i am bound to use camel 2.10 redhat fuse version.

Comment: @Claus Ibsen is there any supported component on Fuse 6.0.0.Redhat24